# Django-CMS installation error

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I tried to install Django-cms by [this tutorial](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/getting_started/tutorial.html#initial-database-setup).

But when I done everything and run command `python manage.py syncdb` -- all I got error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax(forms.py, line 159)

So, what's wrong?

Thank you :)

Comment: Post the entire stack trace

Comment: One reason could be -  You are using `Python 3.x`, but [`django-cms` only supports `Python 2.x`](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.1.3/getting_started/installation.html#requirements)

Comment: that exact , hope he using python 2.x

Comment: Sorry, guys. I was using Python 3.x instead Python 2.5 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

what's OS are you using , if Ubuntu or other linux version , just create django cms clone.

```
git clone https://github.com/divio/django-cms

configure your django-cms in the setting.
hope you have the command git installed.
```